# How do I sync grouped Windows Store apps between devices?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I've grouped my applications in a certain way that I like.  Is there any way to sync this grouping between my Windows 8 devices?

For Example, if I have all of my media apps (Netflix, Hulu, Music, etc,.) all grouped together and named "Entertainment" I would like for these apps to be grouped similarly on all of my devices:

[image]

Comment: it doesn't do this to begin with? I was under the impression that all Windows 8 devices signed in with your Live ID sync those customizations automatically...or is that just the order or background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an option due to the unavailability of some apps on Windows Phone or Windows 8; Tiles may look dramatically different when a tile is missing due to the impossibility of it being installed on the particular Metro platform in question.

It should be possible for someone to make an app that will sync the subsets of each group that are compatible with each device in question. You could try asking the [Microsoft Developer Community](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums) to produce this app.

Comment: They may look different, but it shouldn't be that difficult to notice that certain apps are all together in groups...

Comment: Mcandre is right. There is no desktop sync available. My understanding (from talking to a Win8 developer) is that MS decided against this type of sync for exactly the reasons Mcandre mentions. Not all apps will work on all devices, depending on whether they are mobile, WinRT, etc. In addition, There may be apps that work on my phone and tablet, but I don't want them to appear in both places. Think how cluttered your phone may become if that were the case. I do like the idea of giving folks an option though. It wouldn't be a bad app to write.

Comment: If the Start screens included grayed out dummy tiles for incompatible apps, this could work.