# Transfer Win8 user settings between profiles

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, start-menu, user-profiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sync grouped Windows Store apps between devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/496321/how-do-i-sync-grouped-windows-store-apps-between-devices)

Is there a way for me to copy/save/transfer my "start menu" configuration, meaning the grouping and ordering of the elements on the Start screen, between user profiles?

Is it in the registry?

I am open to manual or "coded" suggestions.

**UPDATE**: I'd like to VETO this closing.  I am aware of the "roaming" profile behavior.  I want to COPY my configuration BETWEEN profiles on the same machine.... DIFFERENT profile DIFFERENT person.  I like the way my start screen is set up.  i want to set my wife up with the same layout.

Comment: Can we re-open or should I re-phrase and re-post?